# SQL total sum by type categories

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an "Expenses" table with columns `ID`, `DATE`, `TYPE` and `AMOUNT`. The `TYPE` column includes different kind of expenses categories, for example rent, food, clothes etc. How could I sum total of each **`TYPE`**? In the end I would like to achieve Pareto kind of chart.

Now I'm able to sum only one by one

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM Expenses WHERE TYPE="Food"
```

Database is MariaDB10 and manipulated with phpMyAdmin if that matters.

Comment: For next time see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, simply, use a `GROUP BY` clause to group your amount for expense type.

In the `SELECT` field list i've added the type, so you can see for each `type` the relative `amount`.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), type FROM Expenses 
group by type
```